# How I can "start" if service is not running, but "reload" if it is running using systemd?

Tags: systemd

I have deployment (capistrano) that, on success, reloads systemd:

```
sudo systemctl reload myserver.service
```

But, just after the first deploy, the service is not yet running. In that case, I want to start it, instead.

```
sudo systemctl start myserver.service
```

Is there a flag or other trick in systemd that figures out: "is the service running, then reload, otherwise, start it"? The alternative would be to build this into the deployment tooling itself, but I'd rather use existing features if systemd provides these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mixed something up. The command to reload or start a systemd service is systemctl.
You can try

```
sudo systemctl reload-or-restart myserver.service
```

That should do what You asked for.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion: I have systemctl aliased to systemd. Because I keep mixing up `systemctl` with `sysctl`. 

But it seems the `reload-or-restart` does what I want it to do.